# Github Actions: Rerun a specific job on existing pull requests once I push to master branch

Tags: github, github-actions, push, workflow, pull-request

I have a current workflow that checks for the commit count difference between 2 branches (prod and main), and this is currently being triggered by opening a pull request that points to branch main or by pushing changes to branch prod. However upon checking, whenever I push to branch prod, the workflow doesn't re-run on my open pull requests, thus the results of the workflow is not updated.

The workflow is triggered like this:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - prod
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
```

I was hoping to find a way to make the workflow re-run on my existing pull requests whenever I push to the prod branch. I've tried using hub but can't seem to get it to work. I've also tried using actions/github-script@v5 but also had no luck.